# Locks don't get released

Tags: locking, lotus-notes

I have a Notes DB where doc. might be edited by diferent users. So i enable locking to avoid conflicts. After working some weeks w/o problems now it seems that locks don't get released after closing of the document. So i disable locking and the users can edit again.

Is there any action (compact, copy) to do, to get that stable again ?

This is a single DB (others working fine) on Domino 8.

Comment: What version of Notes are you running, and is this happening in a single db or across replicas?

Comment: This is a single DB (others working fine) on Domino 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you are saying that this behavior (locked documents not unlocking when users close the document) is persistent (whenever document locking is enabled) and consistent among all users.

You can try a fixup on the database- the server console command would be:

```
Load fixup yourdb.nsf
```

You could also create a "Release All Locks" agent (must be run under an ID with Manager access) with target "All Documents in Database":

```
SELECT @IsAvailable($Writers) | @IsAvailable($PWriters) | @IsAvailable($PTWriters);
@DocLock([UNLOCK])
```

An education-based strategy might be to retrain users to use Actions-Lock Document and Action-Unlock Document rather than relying on automatic locks from editing or closing a document.

A good source for deeper understanding of document locking is [this eView article](http://www.eview.com/eview/volr6.nsf/0/62B3A667117B484385256F3300576ECF/%24File/Guide%20to%20Document%20Locking%20SO%2004.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

These symptoms sound similar to [this](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21236863) issue reported on the IBM support site. Details on the intracacies of Document locking are [here](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003259), suffice to say it's not bullet proof, see [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/ShowMyTopicsAllThreadedweb/4c4477c70ac4094585256c720033c8a9?OpenDocument). If this is the same issue it was [resolved](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/r5fixlist.nsf/Public/0F8368D882C211DD8525717300423D40?OpenDocument) in release 7.0.2 and 6.5.5 FP2. Given that you're using version 8 it should remain fixed, unless it has been introduced as a regression.